# returning a NULL string from a function c++

Tags: c++, string

`string receiveFromServer();`

this function returns a string that was received from some server. If there was an error along the way (including protocol), i want to return a NULL string. However, this doesn't work in c++ (unlike java). 
i tried:

```
string response = receiveFromServer();
if (response==NULL) {
    cerr << "error recive response\n";
}
```

but its not legal.
Since an empty string is also legal to return, what can i return that will indicate the error?

thank you!

Comment: Is not receiving a response an *error*, or just the end of the data stream (expected and normal, but different)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can throw an exception to indicate an error.

```
try {
    std::string response = receiveFromServer();
} catch(std::runtime_error & e) {
    std::cerr << e.what();
}
```

Then you would need a `throw std::runtime_error("Error receive response")` somewhere in `receiveFromServer()`.

It is often considered good practice (though some might disagree) to create your own exception-classes that derive from `std::runtime_error` to enable clients to catch your errors specifically.

Comment: Good suggestion, but why runtime_error? I prefer my own exception types inheriting from std::exception (or some of it's derives)

Answer (score 5):

You can either throw an exception (better way), or return boost::optional< string >, but then you have to check if the return value is valid (this is actually worse).

Comment: Instead of `boost::optional`, you can also use `std::pair<string, bool>`.

Comment: I was going to upvote until you said it was worse. How is that worse? It's what I would do (in fact, I was going to submit an answer showing how but checked for others first).

Comment: @GMan In c++ you should use exceptions for error handling. Checking the return value is for c. By using exceptions, you are using a hidden channel for error handling, making the code more readable. But you already know this, right? :)

Comment: @VJo: I asked a clarifying comment on the question, but I had it in my mind (indeed, not necessarily) that reaching the end of the data stream was not an *error*, just a different result. If it is in fact an error, it should be an exception, but if returning nothing is normal behavior, `optional` is the way to go.

Comment: @GMan But the question states that it is an error. For errors, throw an exception. For that reason, returning anything from the function is actually worse, because you would have to check the result of the function.

Comment: @VJo: Yes, if it's an error we've already agreed. I'm probing the OP to see if that's actually the best course of action.

Answer (score 1):

NULL has only a meaning when using pointers. In java strings are pointers so you can do that.

In C++, if you return an std::string, it must exist. So you have some possibilites

- Throw an exception
- Return a pair with a bool indicating the success
- Return an empty string
- Use a pointer (I strongly discourage that option)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should try to handle [with exceptions](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/exceptions/)

```
 try
  {
    string response = receiveFromServer();
  }
  catch (...)
  {
    cerr << "error recive response\n";
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return an empty string you could also use the function
`string::empty()` to test if it is empty

Comment: I don't know if the question added this after your answer, but... "Since an empty string is also legal to return, what can i return that will indicate the error?"